# How shall i get the value of key connectionid from connection jsonarray.?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-client

Output from Server ....

```
{
 "code": 201,
 "message": "Connection ROH_DB|rsh266939369 created",
 "connections": {"connectionid": "ROH_DB|rsh266939369"},
 "status": "Created"
}
```

```
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: I am returning the output as a string response. Can I convert this to in json formate in jerseyClient or rest api. generally I want this value ( "ROH_DB|rsh266939369") as a string output.

Comment: You could de-derialise it to an object, and then use the properties of the object.

Comment: is these are only JSON fields ? or do you have some more? and can you provide what is this `response` type? why don't you use some JSON library ?

Comment: response type:   ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
     .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

Comment: Instead of this output:{
 "code": 201,
 "message": "Connection ROH_DB|rsh266939369 created",
 "connections": {"connectionid": "ROH_DB|rsh266939369"},
 "status": "Created"
}   I want only this :--- ROH_DB|rsh266939369 as my output